# Compare values in two files and print corresponding columns

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I'm trying to compare the values of Column1 of File1 with Column1 of File2. If a match is found, print the corresponding value from Column2 of File1.  If not found, print Column1 of File1 anyways.

```
$ File1
Harvard     Basketball
Yale        Baseball
Princeton   Football
Stanford    Tennis

$ File2
Rutgers      10 people
Stanford     20 people
Yale         32 people
Tufts        43 people
Harvard      51 people

Desired Output:
Harvard     51 people
Yale        32 people
Princeton
Stanford    20 people
```

I tried the following code:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1]=$2;next} A[$1]{print}' file1 file2
```

However this doesn't give me `Princeton` when column2 is empty, it's omitted entirely.  Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to switch things around a bit

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1]=$2FS$3;next} {print $1,A[$1]}' file2 file1
Harvard 51 people
Yale 32 people
Princeton 
Stanford 20 people
```

Comment: This only prints single digits in the 2nd column, for sample "25" would be cut off to "2".. I edited the question for clarity

Comment: @user1899415, I don't think so. What character are your files delimited by?

Comment: Sorry there were some trailing text that I also want to include.. I edited the question

Comment: thanks! I'm hacking the beginning to be `awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1]=$2FS$3FS$4FS$5FS$6FS$7;next}` ... is there a easy way to just say $2 until the end?

Comment: @user1899415, hackily `awk 'NR==FNR{x=$1;$1="";sub(/^ +/, "");A[x]=$0;next} {print $1,A[$1]}' file2 file1`

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way using [join(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/join.1.html) command:

```
$ join -a 1 -o 1.1 2.2 2.3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
Harvard 51 people
Princeton
Stanford 20 people
Yale 32 people
```

Comment: +1; if you want to make FreeBSD `join` (OSX) happy too, use `-o 1.1,2.2,2.3`.